# Does anybody have any experience with FastDB (C++ in-memory database)?

Tags: c++, sql, database, performance, in-memory-database

[FastDB](http://www.fastdb.org/fastdb.html) is an open-source, in-memory database that's tightly integrated with C++ (it supports a SQL-like query language where tables are classes and rows are objects). Like most IMDBs, it's meant for applications dominated by read access patterns. The algorithms and data structures are optimized for systems that read and write data entirely in main memory (RAM). It's supposed to be very fast, even compared to other in-memory databases, but I can't find any benchmarks online.

I'm considering using FastDB for time-series data, in a project where 1) sub-millisecond random-access read latencies, and 2) millions of rows per second sequential read throughput would be very good to have.

I can't find many references to first-hand experience with FastDB; has anyone here used it? Can you point to any benchmarks of FastDB, especially those  that consider read latency and throughput?

Comment: Is it just me, or does this sound more like an advertisement than a question?

Comment: `@Jerry Coffin:` Didn't mean for it to sound like an advertisement. I wanted to point out its main features (in-memory, no SQL, and C++ integration). I figured that several people here have looked at the different IMDBs and might have some insight into this one.

Comment: Advertisement or not, it's still a valid question. Or at least it would be if there were a question there somewhere.

Comment: `@Mark Ransom:` There was a "?" in there, but I've expanded on the question to make it a little clearer.

Comment: @ConsideringFastDB im a novice on fastdb.when i was trying to work a couple of simple examples to get the whole picture of this database,i stuck at compile time.basically i have no idea what is the correct option for g++.i've copied those specified files to /usr/lib /usr/bin and /usr/include respectively and things still did not work out...

Answer (score 6):

A recent post on an Erlang forum (from 2009): http://www.trapexit.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=49476#49476 has someone (Serge Aleynikov) recommending FastDB for trading systems with sub-millisecond latencies:

> If you don't want to spend too much time coding C++, since you have
> already done good work of abstracting mnesia backend, why don't you
> create an Erlang driver for this database: www.fastdb.org. It's based
> on memory mapped files, implemented in C++, is relatively fast compared
> to other in-memory databases (about 250k lookups/s, 50k inserts/s), has
> time-series capabilities, simple C-API. I implemented FastDB interface
> in several languages, and generally it's good for systems that deal with
> latencies in sub-milliseconds range. It may suffice for you unless you
> need to stay in the low microseconds realm.
>
> My 2c.
>
> Serge

It's pretty intimidating to see people worrying about latencies in the low *microseconds*; I'm considering FastDB for digital signal processing (DSP), where live audio systems generally limit latency to no more than about 10 milliseconds. Of course, if a system responds in milliseconds, we might use input pulses of only a few microseconds in length.

There's no mention of what system was used for the 250K lookups/s, 50K inserts/s. Still, it's a positive sign.